# HTML Footer at bottom screen, but not sticky

Tags: html, css

I want a footer at the bottom of a SCREEN, no matter the size. I've found many many solution for this, but those footers are sticky footers. 
What I'm looking for is a footer what positions at the bottom of the screen, however when the user scrolls down, the footer should scoll too.

In  [this](http://themewagon.com/demo/flusk-responsive-multi-purpose-website-template) the down-arrow is on the bottom of the screen, no matter the screen size. When a user scroll, the arrow scrolls too. This is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe position: fixed ?

Comment: position fixed is exactly what he doesnt want to do ;)

Comment: "What I'm looking for is a footer what positions at the bottom of the screen, however when the user scrolls down, the footer should scoll too." this confused me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you provided us is using a dynamic height on their container element so that the container remains the screenheight no matter what.

This can be acomplished with the following code : https://jsfiddle.net/6jvs0kv3/

Basically what i am doing is calling a javascript function that gets the screen height and makes the main container that height MINUS the footer height, so that the footer stays visible at that case but NOT attached to the screen position like a `position:fixed` would do

**EDIT**
example with content after the "footer" , in that case i wouldnt name the element footer but thats what you are looking for basically : https://jsfiddle.net/6jvs0kv3/1/

Comment: Thank you, this is what I've looked for

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `vh` (viewport height) units in a parent wrapper element:

HTML:

```
<section>
    text1
    <footer>footer text</footer>
</section>
<section>
    text2
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    height: 100vh;
}
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tzeowruj/

Comment: Thank you this is a more most simple solution for what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work properly

https://jsfiddle.net/jd0Lyewt/`enter code here`